# Drag and Drop with restricted drop zones

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

This is my first time trying to use drag and drop controls but I'm having problems figuring out how it works. Currently I have two DIVs and I want to move elements from one div to another. Using draggable allows me to place the DIVS anywhere which is something I don't want, I want to limit the area where the element is draggable.

In the other hand, I've seen the jquery UI examples and they all interact with the droppable element but I need to get the id attribute from the draggable element. This is what I've done so far, and right now I'm not only unable to make divs stay within the limited zone they should but I'm also unable to get the draggable element Id attribute.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/LPWhc/1/

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var id, state;
      state = $(this).attr("name");
      id = $(this).closest(".droppable").attr("id");
      alert("Element Id: " + id);
      alert("Element New State: " + state);
    }
  });
});
```

**Here's an updated fiddle that shows the bug I'm having right now with the draggable effect.
http://jsfiddle.net/LPWhc/3/**

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({ revert: 'invalid'});

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.draggable',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.helper));
            $(".draggable").addClass("item"); 
            $(".item").removeAttr("style");
            $(".item").draggable({
                revert: 'invalid'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Element id can be found with ui.draggable[0].id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
   <div name="list-a" class="droppable">
  <h3>List A</h3>
  <div class="task-wrapper">
      <div class="draggable" id="1" name="1">
          <a href="#">Element 1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="draggable" id="2" name="3">
          <a href="#">Element 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="draggable" id="3" name="3">
          <a href="#">Element 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div name="list-b" class="droppable">
  <h3>List B</h3>
  <div class="task-wrapper">
      <div class="draggable" id="5" name="5">
          <a href="#">Element 5</a>
      </div>
      <div class="draggable" id="6" name="6">
          <a href="#">Element 6</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        var id = $(this).closest(".draggable").attr('id');
    }
});

$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    drop: function(event, ui){
        var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        alert(id);  
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a good start but, I'm moving "draggable" elements between two drop-boxes in your case... when I use your code, it moves nice, but then the original element would remain.

Comment: That's because I was cloning it if you want don't want it to copy I can add to my answer, just give me one minute.

Comment: and if you want to get the element id you would use `var id = $(".item").attr("id");` and that will store it in the variable `id`

Comment: I tried this new example... it works fine if you're moving elemnts inside the divs, but if you're moving elements between divs I noticed it doesn't work because the line "$(".item").removeAttr("style");" that you used before is missing. The strange thing is that after you move the first element, the drag and drop sensation is lost. Please check out here your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pck8G/

Comment: Just give me a few minutes I'll play with it, you want it so you can drag them back and forth and itll get there id on drop right?

Comment: That's right... that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve... Right now it works, but the draggable effect disappears after you do the first drag.

Comment: I updated your jsFiddle, everything is working now. I just had to get the id when you first started the drag that way when it drops it'll be able to find that elements id. Sorry about the confusing I hope that's what you were looking for.  [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pck8G/1/)

Comment: Thanks, the id part is fine, my problem is with the draggable itself... what you did adding the item class and then removing the styles from it is great for what I need, but then, the problem is that after I drag and drop the first element, all draggable elements work strange... that's the second fiddle I sent you... http://jsfiddle.net/Pck8G/3/

Comment: Hmm, are they going to be ordered in like a list? Or do you just want the element to snap to the drop div?

Comment: I really don't mind the order of the list but I do care the looks of it... I mean, I want the element to snap to the drop div keeping the same style that other elements have.

Comment: Okay, I would suggest using jQuery UI `sortable` then I'll probably work out a lot better for you, I'll make a quick jsFiddle to see if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: [Sortable jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pck8G/14/) Check it out and let me know if thats what you were thinking, if so ill add in the code to get an id.